# TCP/Telnet from inside docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim' Docker container, with 2 things on it:
-a custom SDK running on it
-a dotnet5 application that connects to the SDK with TCP

If I connect the the Docker's bash, I can use `telnet localhost 54321` to connect to my SDK successfully

If I run the Windows SDK version on my development computer (Windows), and I run my application IIS Express instead of Docker, I can successfully connect with a telnet library (host 'localhost', port '54321'), this works

However, I want to run both the SDK and my dotnet application in a Docker container, and when I try to connect from inside the container (the same thing that works on the IIS hosted version), this does not work. By running 'telnet localhost 54321' from the docker container commandline I can confirm that the SDK is running. What am I doing wrong?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y telnet
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl1.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpulse0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libasound2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libicu63
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpcre2-16-0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libdouble-conversion1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0


RUN mkdir /sdk

COPY ["Server/Sdk/SomeSDK*", "sdk/"]

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Server/MyProject.Server.csproj", "Server/"]
COPY ["Shared/MyProject.Shared.csproj", "Shared/"]
COPY ["Client/MyProject.Client.csproj", "Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Server/MyProject.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Server"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.Server.dll"]
```

Code (working on IIS, when SDK is running on Windows, but not when both SDK and code are running inside the same Docker container):

```
var telnetClient = new TelnetClient("localhost", 54321, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), new CancellationToken());
await telnetClient.Connect();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
await telnetClient.Send("init");
```

Command line (working BOTH from windows CLI, and from Docker bash (so also when the code is not working, this is working):

```
$telnet localhost 54321
$init
```

The issue might be (but I'm not sure, as I've received this result from using direct command line '$telnet localhost 54321' from within dotnet: 'telnet: connection refused by remote host'

Comment: Please check if Telnet is activated in the container:
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient

Comment: Are both parts running in a single container, or in two separate containers, or one in a container and one not?  How is the SDK component's network listener configured (what address and port does it listen on)?

Comment: @markus I will check and get back to you, but telnet works from the command line inside the Docker container so I assume it works

Comment: @David both are inside the same container. The SDK listens to TCP connections on port 54321

Comment: pls club your run statements into a single statement

Comment: This is probably a VERY long reach, but could it be possible with Docker on Windows (when using a linux container) that you need to explicitly EXPOSE the port 54321?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use in your `docker run` command also `--network=host` to use the same network if you want to reach out of the container or create a bridge with `--network=bridge` (for example with another container).

By default the Docker container is spawn on a separate, dedicated and private subnet on your machine (mostly [`172.17.0.0/16`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/)) which is different from your machine's default/local subnet ([`127.0.0.0/8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Name_resolution)).

For connecting into the host's subnet in this case `127.0.0.0/8` you need `--network=host`. For communication within the same container though it's not necessary and works out of the box.

For accessing the service in container from the outside you need to make sure you have your application's port published either with `--publish HOST_PORT:DOCKER_PORT` or `--publish-all` (random port(s) on host are then assigned, check with `docker ps`).

#### Host to container (normal)

```
# host
telnet <container's IP> 8000  # connects, typing + return shows in netcat stdout

# container
docker run --rm -it --publish 8000:8000 alpine nc -v -l -p 8000
```

#### Container to host (normal)

```
# host
nc -v -l -p 8000

# container, docker run -it alpine
apk add busybox-extras
telnet localhost 8000  # hangs, is dead
```

#### Container to host (on host network)

```
# host
nc -v -l -p 8000

# container, docker run -it --network=host alpine
apk add busybox-extras
telnet localhost 8000  # connects, typing + return shows in netcat stdout
```

#### Within container

```
# start container
docker run -it --name alpine alpine
apk add busybox-extras

# exec into container to create service on 4000
docker exec -it alpine nc -v -l -p 4000

# exec into container to create service on 5000
docker exec -it alpine nc -v -l -p 5000

# telneting from the original terminal (the one with apk add)
telnet localhost 4000  # connects, works 
telnet localhost 5000  # connects, works
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly - both applications are running inside the same docker container. Does this still apply then?

Comment: Yes, if you want to reach them from the host machine or from a different subnet you need to either use directly the host's network or use a bridge.

Comment: You shouldn't normally need host networking, and you shouldn't normally need to look up the container-private IP addresses if you're using bridged networking.  Neither of these things work on a Windows host.

Comment: You have a single container running both the SDK and dotnet application right? There should not be any problem when you use localhost for intracontainer connection. Could we please see the Dockerfile? 

On another note, containers should have single responsibility, so it might be better to separate the SDK and app if they are connecting over TCP (I don't know your use case though, so it might make sense on your case) Finally are you using windows? Windows container networking is screwed up

Comment: I did not give the down vote, I don't know why. Both are running in the same container. @Yamuk I will add the Docker file in an hour. With regards to your other point, I have business constraints that makes this necessary.

Comment: @DavidMaze Re IPs, it's to illustrate that the application is separated from the normal host's IP subnet. There wasn't any step for lookup mentioned anywhere, just using `--network` flag to connect those subnets either by having the container on 127.x.x.x or having a bridge between those subnets. Re the host networking, if you want to reach **out** of the container you need to specify what network you want to connect to and how, otherwise it'll be just blocked because it won't be seen/reachable from the container.

Comment: @DaniëlCamps Check the examples

Comment: @PeterBadida if I understand correctly, calling the SDK (located inside the Docker container) from the dotnet code (running inside the same container) should work with localhost? That's what I thought, but that's also what's not working. I think I have a '“telnet: connection refused by remote host”' error, but I'm not sure as I'm trying it in a different way, but that might be the issue

Comment: @DaniëlCamps Try to run a port scan such as `nmap -p- localhost` in the container itself, it'll show you if your port is open and if it's the same one you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @PeterBadida I just did it - it shows '54321/tcp open', two other SDK ports open (which are not relevant for now), and 80 and 443 open (http and https)

Comment: @DaniëlCamps Try to switch from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in your .NET TelnetClient, maybe it's a problem with the name resolution within that client? Otherwise, I'm rather speechless.

Comment: @PeterBadida I already tried that before posting the question (I was thinking the same thing). It doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: To improve on the name resolution case, did you try defining an IP explicitly and use it? 172.x.x.x It is not a good practice but may be help you debug the issue.